# Write each record in new line using ZFile To write into a file?

Tags: java, file-io, file-writing, java-batch

I have a Java batch job and I am writing into a file in the writer.

I am writing into a MVS Dataset and using ZFile's write(byte[] buf) to write into the file.

However instead of writing each record in a new line it is being written in the same line (even though there is a "\n" in the Java string at the end). Is there any parameter that needs to be passed for this?

The recfm is fb and type is record. The record length is 80, but all records may not be of length 80

```
String pdsName = ZFile.getSlashSlashQuotedDSN("A.B.C.D");
try {
    //  dsnFile = new ZFile(pdsName ,"wb,type=record,recfm=fb,lrecl=80,noseek");                
} catch (ZFileException e) {                    
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for(Object o: listOfStrings){
    String s = (String)o;
    try {
        dsnFile.write(s.getBytes());
    } catch (ZFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste some sample code?

Comment: added sample code :)

Comment: @FazilHussain Were you able to get each record on a new line, I am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @User2709 i had to pad all strings with spaces to meet the record length

Comment: @FazilHussain  thanks, I could get that working by adding a \n and calling flush() after writing each line to the file.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to open output file in "Write Binary" format. you can try to use "Write Text" instead

```
    dsnFile = new ZFile(pdsName ,"wt,recfm=fb,lrecl=80,blksize=0");
```